# Current-generation volume in current-generation EC2 instance does not behave as a Elastic Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a `t2.medium` instance with a `gp2` volume, my region is `eu-west-1`.

[In theory](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-elastic-volumes-change-everything/) this is a current-generation EC2 instance with a current-generation EBS volume so it should support live updates because it should be a *Elastic Volume*.

However, after choosing **Modify Volume**, I get this warning message:

> This volume attachment may not support live volume modifications, and
>   your request may not succeed.

If I go ahead and try to change the volume size, I get the following error:

> Modification is not supported for volume vol-01234567 in its current
>   state in-use. Please detach the volume or stop the attached instance
>   and retry.

Why is my volume not behaving as a Elastic Volume?  Is it because it was created before the feature was announced or am I missing anything?

Comment: When did you launch the instance? windows or linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure when your instance was launched. From [Considerations for Modifying EBS Volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/considerations.html)

> Before you can modify a volume that was attached to an instance
>   **before November 1, 2016**, you must initialize volume modification support using one of the following actions:

- Detach and attach the volume
- Restart the instance

Comment: That fixed it.  Although instead of restarting the instance, I had to stop it and start it (i.e. shutdown instead or restart).

Comment: @Pep re*start* as used here is equivalent to stop followed by start.  The alternative is re*boot*, which would not accomplish the purpose.